sqlite, split content of fetchall() output
basically i'm creating a webapp on flask, just a simple menu connected to a database, and i'm having issues with the variants of an item
that's my db structure:
product_name | product_category | product_variants | product price | description

categories = get_db().execute("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products ORDER BY category DESC").fetchall()
allDict = {}
for category in categories:
    products = get_db().execute("SELECT name,variants,prices,description FROM products WHERE category=?", (category[0],)).fetchall()
    allDict[category[0]] = products
return render_template("home.html", allDict=allDict)

but i have an issue, the product variants and price of the variant (only one price if  is the same) are separed with a / symbol and i want to split them to have control over position and style with css cause they are separated elements
otherwise i have just a string and i can't manipulate that
example
after i do this
products = get_db().execute("SELECT name,variants,prices,description FROM products WHERE category=?", (category[0],)).fetchall()

i get something like this: [('waffle', 'big/normal/baby', '5$/4$/3$', 'very good waffle')]
also i can't create a column for every variant because idk how mutch variant can a product have
so what is the best solution in terms of performance?
tried already to use split method or transform the tuple as a list but I think there is a better way to handle this problem

allDict is a bad way to name dictionaryContainingAllDbThings btw

Why do you need the first query? Why not just SELECT name,variants,prices,description FROM products ORDER by category?

Don't put the variants and prices in strings like that. You should normalize your database by creating a product_variants table. It has columns product_id (FK to products), variant, and price.

What is your desired result?

i think your second response is the solution i should use, i want to have a website with something like, category title: sweets, then the product name with all the variants and prices on the right of the variant, and so on for every product inside the category and every category like drinks

So you need the following tables: category, product (with FK to category), product_variant (with FK to product).

And if a product can be in multiple categories (e.g. "Diet Coke" is in the drinks and diet categories), you need a joining table product_categories that contains FK to category and product, rather than putting a category_id FK in product.

perfect, i’ll try to do the database, if i find any issue i’ll comment below, thank you!
